# Keras' predict_generator not returning correct number of samples

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a custom data generator that reads data from csv file(s) in chunks using `pandas.read_csv`. I tested it with `model.predict_generator` but the number of predictions returned is less than expected (in my case, 248192 out of 253457).

Custom generator

```
class TestDataGenerator:

def __init__(self, directory, batch_size=1024):
    self.directory = directory
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.chunk_size=10000
    self.samples = 0

def _to_movie_id(self, ids):
    ids = ast.literal_eval(ids)
    if ids == []:
        return [EMB_MATRIX_SIZE-1]
    else:
        return [movie2idx[str(movie_id)] for movie_id in ids]

def generate(self):
    csv_files = glob.glob(self.directory + '/*.csv')
    while True:
        for file in csv_files:
            df = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=self.chunk_size)
            for df_chunk in df:
                chunk_steps = math.ceil(len(df_chunk) / self.batch_size)
                for i in range(chunk_steps):
                    batch = df_chunk[i * self.batch_size:(i + 1) * self.batch_size]
                    X_batch, y_batch = self.preprocess(batch)
                    self.samples += len(batch)
                    yield X_batch, y_batch


def preprocess(self, df):
    X_user = df['user'].apply(lambda x: user2idx[str(x)]).values
    X_watched = df['watched'].apply(self._to_movie_id).values
    X_watched_padded = pad_sequences(X_watched, maxlen=SEQ_LENGTH, value=0)

    ohe = df['movie'].apply(lambda x: to_categorical(movie2idx[x], num_classes=len(movie2idx)))
    X = [X_user, X_watched_padded]
    y = np.array([o.tolist() for o in ohe])

    return X, y
```

Run `model.predict_generator`

```
batch_size=1024
n_samples_test = 253457
test_dir = 'folder/'
test_gen = TestDataGenerator(test_dir, batch_size=batch_size)
next_test_gen = test_gen.generate()
preds = model.predict_generator(next_test_gen, steps=math.ceil(n_samples_test/batch_size))
```

After running `model.predict_generator`, the number of rows for `preds` is `248192` which is less than the actual `253457`. It looks like it's missing a few number of epochs. I also tested `generate` individually without interacting with Keras and it behaved as expected returning the correct number of samples in csv file. Also, before the `generate` yields a value, I keep track of the number of samples processed with `samples`. Surprisingly, the value for `samples` is 250000. So, I'm pretty sure I might have done something with Keras.

Note that I also tried setting `max_queue_size=1`, and making `generate` thread-safe but got no luck. I placed only 1 csv file under `test_dir` for simplicity. I'm using Keras 2.1.2-tf embedded in Tensorflow 1.5.0.

I did some research on how this can be done but haven't come across a useful example yet. What is wrong with this implementation?

Thanks

Peeranat F.

Comment: Just from curiosity - could you check how `preds[::1024]` vector looks like?

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is tricky. So let's dive into the problem:

1. **How `fit_generator` works when batch provided is less than `batch_size`**: As you may see - many batches you provide to `fit_generator` are of the size less than `batch_size`. This happens every time when you take the last batch from every file. Usually - a number of texts are not divisible by batch size so there are not enough texts to fill the batch. This ends up in feeding less examples to a model.

   And here is a tricky part - `keras` ignores less size, treats this as valid generator step and returns values for an incomplete batch.
2. **So why there are texts missing:** let me show you by example. Let's assume that you have 2 files with 5 texts each and your `batch_size` is 4. This is how your batches would look like:

   ```
   [1t1, 1t2, 1t3, 1t4], [1t5,], [2t1, 2t2, 2t3, 2t4], [2t5].
   ```

   As you may see - the actual number of steps needed is equal to `4` which is not equal to `3` which is obtained by taking: `math.ceil(10 / 4)`. This way is appropriate for these batches:

   ```
   [1t1, 1t2, 1t3, 1t4], [1t5, 2t1, 2t2, 2t3], [2t4, 2t5]
   ```

   But batches returned from your generator are not like these.
3. **How to solve the problem?** - you need to make your generator to compute the actual number of steps needed:

   ```
   def steps_needed(self):
       steps = 0
       csv_files = glob.glob(self.directory + '/*.csv')
       for file in csv_files:
       df = pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=self.chunk_size)
       for df_chunk in df:
           chunk_steps = math.ceil(len(df_chunk) / self.batch_size)
           steps += chunk_steps
       return steps
   ```

   This function computes exactly how many batches your generator will return.

Cheers :)

Comment: Great explanation and example. I solved the problem. Thank you very much :)